# Reverse engineering on SVG path template to write another word with same path pattern

Tags: html, svg, path

I'm interested at this type of logo:
[image: Logo]

[Html Code](http://pastebin.com/MjnCyXXP)

I am not an expert in graphic, so I was wondering, what Have I to do to obtain written SocialNet Instead of Phandroid?

The demo of this template is avaible at this link:
[Template](http://phandroid.com/page/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just change a text inside the svg. Instead you must use an application that can save vector graphics in svg format. Adobe illustrator can do that. There are probably some free alternatives available too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You shouldn't just steal other peoples work.

If Phandroid are using a predefined font for their logo, then you should search out which font it is and purchase it if it is a commercial one.

If it isn't an available free or commercial font, then those letter designs are Phandroid's property, and you shouldn't be trying to copy their work.

If, *and only if*, you happen to have permission to do this, then you should load the file into an SVG editor (for example Inkscape) and split apart the path using the path editing tools.

Alternatively you could do it manually, in a text editor, by splitting the path string into nine separate paths. Each one should start with an "M" (move) path command.  But even then you are only part way solution. Their logo only has three of the letters you need.